# Using PostGIS as editable database with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: postgis, arcgis-pro, editing

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.5 I can connect to our PostgreSQL/PostGIS database (9.6.15/2.3), but I cannot edit the features. In ArcGIS Pro I get the error message:

> The enterprise database table is not registered with the Geodatabase.
> Edits cannot be made.

Can I use ArcGIS Pro 2.5 to connect to our PostgreSQL/PostGIS database to make revisions and edits to existing data?

Answer (score 6):

You can create connection in ArcGIS Pro to PostgreSQL.

You need to create a **non-system** role to be able to connect

[image]

Comment: Is this for full edits or read-only?

Comment: @Nico for editing, you require Enterprise Geodatabase ArcGIS Enterprise (Server) License.

Comment: "Read-mostly" would be more accurate. ArcGIS clients use Esri's optimistic locking (versioned) editing model for the editing GUI. PostgreSQL stands alone among the Enterprise geodatabase RDBMS implementations, because you can use a non-geodatabase instance as a target for FeatureClassToFeatureClass, FeatureClassToGeodatabase, and most other utilities, so it's certainly not read-only.  You can also edit non-EGDB tables with DA InsertCursor and UpdateCursor sessions, and submit arbitrary SQL with `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute`, which includes INSERT, UPDATE, and CREATE statements.

Comment: I have been hunting down this same question for a while. The question is now fairly focused. And it's not only connect and edit PostgreSQL. It includes reading and writing PostGIS geo data types, indexes and functions.

Comment: I need to walk back the DA UpdateCursor compatibility comment.  **Don't** try to use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor` without an enterprise geodatabase enabled.   DA SearchCursor works fine.